# Raspberry Pi doesn't recognize HP PSC 750xi Scanner

Tags: python, scanner, lsusb, sane, hplip

I posted this to [raspberrypi.stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135290/raspberry-pi-doesnt-recognize-hp-psc-750xi-scanner) yesterday with no responses and only 4 views, so I'm reposting and expanding the original post here to reach a wider/different audience.

I have an old Pi-3 running Stretch. I have what `apt-get install` tells me is the latest version of everything installed. I plug in an old HP PSC 750xi All-In-One USB printer/scanner. The Pi recognizes the printer features of the device, and I can successfully configure CUPS to use the printer. But I cannot get the Pi to recognize the device's scanner.

I have a separate laptop running Ubuntu 20. When I plug the USB device into that laptop, I can use hplip's `hp-scan` tool to successfully scan. But none of the Pi's `hplip` or `sane` tools (`hp-setup`, `hp-probe`, `hp-check`, `hp-scan`, `scanimage`, `sane-find-scanner` ...) recognize the USB scanner.

Clearly, as the Ubuntu test proves, `hplip` **does** support scanning for this all-in-one printer/scanner. And `hplip` documentation indicates that the device is supported both for the Pi `hplip` version (3.16.11) and for the Ubuntu version (3.20).

I also have an HP 6978 Network printer/scanner that the Ubuntu system sees on the network and can manipulate with the `hplip` tools. The Pi's CUPS server sees and can use that network printer. But, like the USB device, the Pi fails to 'see' the network scanner.

My understanding is that these scanners are supported through use of the `libsane-hpaio` backend. Yes, I have installed the `libsane-hpaio` package on the Pi. I've run `scanimage` on the Pi with `SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128` and `SANE_DEBUG_HPAIO=128` but the output simply reports no scanners found without indicating any errors of any kind. On the Ubuntu system, the same debug output shows successful discovery of both the network scanner and the USB-connected scanner.

But there appear to be more fundamental issues.  The full `lsusb` output is now reporting:

```
theadmin@RASSERVER:~ $ lsusb
Protocol spec without prior Class and Subclass spec at line 23291
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 03f0:1511 HP, Inc PSC 750xi
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It's that very first line I'm concerned about.  I'm thinking this is a possible `Python` version issue as `python -V` reports `Python 2.7.13`.  But Python3.5 is installed too (though I have no idea which package might have installed it,) and `python3 -V` reports `Python 3.5.3`.

So, I'm thinking half the packages are using `python` v2 and half are using v3 and I don't know which is using which.  Nor do I know how to configure them to use a different version.  Plus, I'm a bit hesitant to even try to reconfigure/upgrade the base python from v2 to v3 for fear of breaking the entire system.  And I'm concerned that the `libusb` and `usbutil` packages are so old, while `hplip` and its companions are much newer ... some kind of a mismatch somewhere, but I hardly know where to start.  I hate to rebuild the Pi from scratch because I don't want to have to rebuild its LAMP stack, web server, nextcloud server, etc. but that may be my only option.

I cannot find any missing packages or dependencies on the Pi. I have tried removing and re-installing `hplip` and a number of other packages. Clearly, there is some configuration difference between the Pi and the Ubuntu platforms. But after several days of struggle, I'm stumped.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Stretch is really old. Its successor has also been replaced, so your easy upgrade path has now disappeared. You might be able to upgrade to oldstable (buster), which is broadly level with Ubuntu 20, and then you might find your scanner works. But that's a lot of _might_ and _maybe_.

Comment: Thanks @roaima.  Yeah.  Stretch is almost as old as I am.  ;-)  While I wait for potential solutions, I burned a micro-SD with `raspios-bullseye` from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/) and fired it up.  Printing and scanning to the problematic HP-750xi worked right out of the box without any configuration whatsoever.  Total time: < 1 hour.  Of course, I'll spend the next week rebuilding the other apps.  But it's a hopeful start.

Comment: If you've the spare card, clone your existing setup and try and upgrade to oldstable and then to buster. Your LAMP configurations might carry through successfully. If it fails you're no worse off than you are now, barring a couple more hours of tinkering. FWIW I recently upgraded 15 Pi servers from stretch to buster. All but three updated perfectly. The remaining three I'm going to need to post out new cards for (all but one of the 15 are in remote locations). Not a terrible ratio, really

Comment: The problem with that is that my existing card is 128G and I don't have another 128G card.  As noted below, I'm working to rebuild Buster now on a 64G card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of further suggestions, I've decided that the way ahead is to rebuild my system using the latest Raspberry Pi OS.  It's the 'nuclear option' but preferrable to spending another week or two struggling to fix a probably-unfixable issue on a years-old OS.